# How can I use my WebCam on a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, macos-mojave

My host is MacOs Mojave, and I have a virtual machine with windows10. I need to use my webcam (built-in) on the virtual machine, but I can't because "A webcam is not found"
What should I do??

Comment: What Hypervisor is hosting the VM? Answers will depend greatly on this and so this information must be included in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using VirtualBox (as shown in your tags), if you're using your computer's webcam:
  1. Install VirtualBox Extension Pack
  2. Open your virtual machine
  3. On top of the window, there's a menu `Devices`, go to `Devices > Webcams`, click on your webcam device name.